# Convert iPhone app to be iPhone and iPad apps (not universal)

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-universal-app

I've an existing iPhone app.

I need to create a separate app for iPad app (and of course use shared code).

But have the two apps to be uploaded to apple store as one app.

Is creating a new target fit my case? If yes can you provide me with step by step tutorial?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you want the app store to show a single app you have to upload it as a universal app. You can't upload an iPhone app and an iPad app and have them show up as a single app in the store.